# EditText in CollapsingToolbar hidden behind soft keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an `EditText` in the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and sometimes there is a situation when on `EditText` focus the soft keyboard covers the `EditText`.
Other `EditTexts` outside of the `CollapsingToolbar` behave as expected - the coordinator layout scrolls so that they are visible and I would like to have that here.

I found a solution that I could change `windowSoftInputMode` in `AndroidManifest.xml` but I cant do it here because of other views that have to stay as they are. Currently it is set to 'adjustResize'.

Is is possible to maybe scroll the `CoordinatorLayout` programatically so that the `EditText` stays visible when clicked?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]